# Query that finds the names of the directors that played in movies that they directed

Tags: ms-access

Given database of the website "eMovies" that manage data about cinema movies.

> Write in SQL query that finds the names of the directors that played in movies that they directed

[image]

The tables:

```
Actors 
    ActorID      PK
    Firstname 
    LastName

Directors 
    DirectorID   PK
    Firstname 
    LastName

Genres 
    GenreID      PK
    GenreDescr 

Movies 
    MovieID      PK
    MovieName 
    Year

ActorsMovies 
    MovieID      PK
    ActorID      PK 

DirectorsMovies 
    MovieID      PK
    DirectorID   PK 

GenresMovies 
    MovieID      PK
    GenreID      PK
```

**My attempt:**

```
 SELECT Directors.FirstName, Directors.LastName
 FROM Directors, DirectorsMovies,ActorsMovies
 WHERE Directors.DirectorID=DirectorsMovies.DirectorID=ActorsMovies.ActorID
 GROUP BY FirstName,LastName;
```

In the output I see an empty table, someone can tell me why and how can I improve my code? or any other working code please?.

Comment: Definitely stop using the old style `JOIN` syntax. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INNER-JOIN-Operation-b9e73ab6-884a-403e-9f22-cb502feae36a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a set of direct joins and on the filter clause you can check the names of actor to fit of the director.

Note also this avoids cases where someone is an actor of another director movie but is also one director of another movie (where he/she is not an actor).

I used explicit join because they are prefearable over implicit ones.

```
select distinct d.Firstname, d.LastName
from dbo.Directors d
join dbo.DirectorsMovies dm on dm.DirectorID = d.DirectorID
join dbo.ActorMovies am on am.MovieID = dm.MovieID
join dbo.Actors a on a.ActorID = am.ActorID
where d.Firstname = a.Firstname
and d.LastName = a.LastName
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer based on @jean's answer, I fixed some small mistaks **this** code is working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Directors.FirstName, Directors.LastName
FROM ((Directors INNER JOIN DirectorsMovies ON DirectorsMovies.DirectorID = Directors.DirectorID) 
INNER JOIN ActorsMovies ON ActorsMovies.MovieID =  DirectorsMovies.MovieID)   
INNER JOIN Actors ON Actors.ActorID = ActorsMovies.ActorID
WHERE Directors.FirstName =Actors.FirstName
AND Directors.LastName = Actors.LastName;
```